# TCL expect -re match

Tags: tcl, expect

I am trying to get information with telnet at different machines. To do this i am using the Expect package. My problem is to expect the right prompt because the machines has two different prompt -> or =>. I try to do this with

`expect -re "(->|=>) $"`

but it doesn't work. I have do it now like set prompt "->" or "=>" before but I think with expect -re it has to work either?

Comment: `expect -d /your/script.exp` and see what's happening.

Comment: That looks OK. Are you sure there's a space at the end? Use `expect -d` to see how your patterns are (not) matching.

Comment: While we normally recommend putting regular expressions in braces, it shouldn't matter in this case.